# display functions variables in different places

Tags: php, function, variables

Can someone explain how to display different variables in different places in HTML template? I want `$row['fullname']` in header and in right sidebar another variables? Thank you! I read about global variables but I avoid to use at the moment global variables. If I put new parameter for function is viable? (I dont think so)

```
function viewMember($mysqli, $member)
{
    $ret = "";
    $statement = $mysqli->query(
        "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$member' "
    );
    $row = $statement->fetch_array();
    $ret = $ret . 'User ID:' . htmlentities($row['id']) . '</br>
                   Full Name: ' . htmlentities($row['fullname']) . '</br>
                   Username: ' . htmlentities($row['username']) . '</br>
                   Email: ' . htmlentities($row['email']) . '   </br>
                   Last Login: ' . htmlentities($row['last_online']) . '</br>
                   Last IP: ' . htmlentities($row['last_ip']) . '<br/>
                   Last Browser: ' . htmlentities($row['http_agent']) . '<br/>
                   System Role : ' . htmlentities($row['role']) . '';
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: You probably could get away with using sessions.

Comment: what? i didnt understand!

Comment: Use session variables. `$var=$_SESSION['var'];` then `echo $var;` anywhere after that.

Comment: If you want to put a var into the page title, you put it where you would normally put the text version of what you want there.

Comment: you didnt understand i want in page title $row['fullname'] and in footer page $row['http_agent'] this is the problem

Comment: You must return all data from this method in an array before showing any part of the template so that you can consume this data in your template. Returning html you can't do the way you want.

Comment: @user3671720 How do you do to call this method, with ajax or before mounting the html page?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help you!

<?php

session_start();

function viewMember($mysqli,$member)
 {      
 $ret = "";

$statement = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username =    '$member' ");
                $row = $statement->fetch_array();
                $ret =
                $ret.'User ID:'.htmlentities($row['id']).'  </br>
                Full Name: ' .htmlentities($row['fullname']).'</br>
                Username: '  .htmlentities($row['username']).'</br>
                Email: '     .htmlentities($row['email']).'   </br>
                Last Login: '.htmlentities($row['last_online']).'</br>
                Last IP: '   .htmlentities($row['last_ip']).'<br/>
                Last Browser: '.htmlentities($row['http_agent']).'<br/>
                System Role : '.htmlentities($row['role']).'';





        $_SESSION['id']=htmlentities($row['id']);
                $_SESSION['fullname']=htmlentities($row['fullname']);
                $_SESSION['username']=htmlentities($row['username']);
                $_SESSION['email']=htmlentities($row['email']);
                $_SESSION['last_online']=htmlentities($row['last_online']);
               $_SESSION['last_ip']= htmlentities($row['last_ip']);
                $_SESSION['http_agent']=htmlentities($row['http_agent']);
               $_SESSION['role']= htmlentities($row['role']);








              return $ret;
             }
             ?>
      // Echo following variables wherever you want         
        $_SESSION['id'];
                $_SESSION['fullname'];
                $_SESSION['username'];
                $_SESSION['email'];
                $_SESSION['last_online'];
               $_SESSION['last_ip'];
                $_SESSION['http_agent'];
               $_SESSION['role'];
```